# Swords in The Hobbit

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit

Why don't Orcrist / Goblin-cleaver and Glamdring / Foe-hammer glow like Sting when orcs/goblins are near?

Comment: They do. All of the blades forged by the ancient Calaquendi elves did that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the book, they did.

Chapter 4, Over Hill and Under Hill, page 64:

> Suddenly a sword flashed in its own light.

(Gandalf wielding Glamdring the Foe-Hammer/Biter)

page 65:

> He took out his sword again, and again it flashed in the dark by
>   itself. It burned with a rage that made it gleam if goblins were
>   about; now it was bright as blue flame for delight in the killing of
>   the great lord of the cave.

Why they don't in the movie, is never said.  I can think of no in-universe answer.

Comment: I did not realise that. So I guess the reason is most likely because it was quite unimportant in the books, so was not a  priority in the movie. And it likely made them look far too much like light sabers.

I could have sworn I remembered the book having Gandalf describe Sting as special, even for a Elvish blade, and that was why it glowed and none of the others did.